# Keep getting message: Failed allocate pages: FAIL_PAGE_ALLOCATION 540

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, error-log

I'd appreciate some help with the following, I've done some Googling, but haven't managed to resolve this one.

I keep receiving a message in the SQL Log 'Failed allocate pages: FAIL_PAGE_ALLOCATION 540', followed by a dump which I'll add to the end of this question.

For your information, the build is:

- Virtual Server running on vCenter
- Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit SQL
- Server 2012 SP1 Enterprise (11.0.2100) 8GB RAM SQL Server Max and Min memory is set to 6144 MB

The server is part of a 2 node Availability Group, this is the current primary node.

This instance is hosting the databases for Microsoft SharePoint

I ran a Perfmon trace for 24 hours which only revealed PLE dropping after one of the dumps, and then rising back up. Nothing else particularly odd.

SQL Server is still running.

## EXTRACT FROM SQL LOG:

```
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,CACHESTORE_XMLDBELEMENT (node 0)                 KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                   8
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,CACHESTORE_XMLDBTYPE (node 0)                    KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                   8
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,CACHESTORE_VIEWDEFINITIONS (node 0)              KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                  16
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,CACHESTORE_NOTIF (node 0)                        KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                  16
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,CACHESTORE_TEMPTABLES (node 0)                   KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                 448
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,CACHESTORE_XPROC (node 0)                        KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                 120
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,CACHESTORE_PHDR (node 0)                         KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                              157688
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,CACHESTORE_SQLCP (node 0)                        KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                              886856
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,CACHESTORE_OBJCP (node 0)                        KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                              409760
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_FSCHUNKER (node 0)                   KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                  48
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_LWC (node 0)                         KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                   8
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SQLLOGPOOL (node 0)                  KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                8208
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_HADR (node 0)                        KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                 688
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_XE (node 0)                          KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                              218176
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_FILETABLE (node 0)                   KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                  16
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SQLSERVICEBROKERTRANSPORT (node 0)         KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                 232
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_FULLTEXT_SHMEM (node 0)              KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                      24<nl/>SM Committed                                     24<nl/>Pages Allocated                                   0
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SOSMEMMANAGER (node 0)               KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                  474880<nl/>VM Committed                                 474736<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                   0
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SOSOS (node 0)                       KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                 192
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SOSNODE (Total)                      KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                               71968
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SOSNODE (node 64)                    KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                2432
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SOSNODE (node 0)                     KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                               69536
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_HOST (node 0)                        KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                  24
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_XTP (node 0)                         KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                  16
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_XE_BUFFER (node 0)                   KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                  206208<nl/>VM Committed                                 206208<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                   0
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SQLQERESERVATIONS (node 0)           KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                1328
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_BHF (node 0)                         KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                 192
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SQLXP (node 0)                       KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                  16
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_FULLTEXT (node 0)                    KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                 296
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SNI (Total)                          KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                1024
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SNI (node 64)                        KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                  16
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SNI (node 0)                         KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                1008
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SQLHTTP (node 0)                     KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                   8
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SQLSERVICEBROKER (node 0)            KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                 984
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SQLCLR (node 0)                      KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                 1603008<nl/>VM Committed                                  28096<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                4816
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SQLCONNECTIONPOOL (node 0)           KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                               20464
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SQLSTORENG (node 0)                  KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                   23040<nl/>VM Committed                                  23040<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                               40144
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SQLUTILITIES (node 0)                KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                 408
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SQLOPTIMIZER (node 0)                KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                2224
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SQLQUERYEXEC (node 0)                KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                                2856
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL (node 0)               KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                 3251552<nl/>VM Committed                                 137416<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                             3188808
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,MEMORYCLERK_SQLGENERAL (node 0)                  KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                      0<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>SM Reserved                                       0<nl/>SM Committed                                      0<nl/>Pages Allocated                               23920
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,Memory node Id = 64                              KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                                       0<nl/>VM Committed                                     20<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,Memory node Id = 0                               KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                               274536504<nl/>VM Committed                                6291428<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>Pages Allocated                             5393336<nl/>Pages Free                                    10504<nl/>Target Committed                            6291432<nl/>Current Committed                           6291432<nl/>Foreign Committed                                 0<nl/>Away Committed                                    0
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,Memory Manager                                   KB<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>VM Reserved                               274536568<nl/>VM Committed                                6291448<nl/>Locked Pages Allocated                            0<nl/>Large Pages Allocated                             0<nl/>Emergency Memory                               1024<nl/>Emergency Memory In Use                          16<nl/>Target Committed                            6291456<nl/>Current Committed                           6291448<nl/>Pages Allocated                             5393336<nl/>Pages Reserved                                 1224<nl/>Pages Free                                    10504<nl/>Pages In Use                                3093536<nl/>Page Alloc Potential                        2883352<nl/>NUMA Growth Phase                                 2<nl/>Last OOM Factor                                   2<nl/>Last OS Error                                     0
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,Process/System Counts                         Value<nl/>---------------------------------------- ----------<nl/>Available Physical Memory                 787546112<nl/>Available Virtual Memory                 8514575921152<nl/>Available Paging File                    8859074560<nl/>Working Set                              6637367296<nl/>Percent of Committed Memory in WS               100<nl/>Page Faults                               256980685<nl/>System physical memory high                       1<nl/>System physical memory low                        0<nl/>Process physical memory low                       0<nl/>Process virtual memory low                        0
10/03/2014 09:59:52,spid866,Unknown,Failed allocate pages: FAIL_PAGE_ALLOCATION 540
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there are only 8208 pages allocated to MEMORYCLERK_SQLLOGPOOL in the excerpt not sure kb2769594 is the culprit/fix.
Also no reference to internal pool or HADR as in the kb2769594 example.
https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2769594

So I think culprit/fix may be something else.

Surprising that no large pages allocated at all - I'd expect some for non-bpool with 8 gb of RAM on the server.
SQL Server Enterprise edition?
Low system memory is somewhat suprising - is there another large memory consumer beside SQL Server?
Which OS version?  Is the NTFS file cache well under control?

*edit*
Via twitter also asked if 'lock pages in memory' LPIM is expected - no locked pages indicated above.

Comment: Thanks again, these are dedicated SQL Server nodes running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise. There aren't any other large memory consumers that I can see. 

edit - as tweeted, LPIM was configured but not working as the DBEngine Service account had been changed, but Secpol hadn't been update.

Comment: Just to update this. After re-instigating Lock Pages In Memory (by adding the correct service account!) I have so far stopped receiving the error. I will leave it 24 hours to make sure. Nice spot though!

Comment: I've not seen the error for about 30 hours since sorting out LPIM. This seems to have helped, I will also be upgrading our dev and test environments (of which this is included) to SP2 over maintenance weekend. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Just to provide another answer. I just ran into the same error messages and this issue seems to be related yet not the same issue fixed in the KB linked in the other 2 answers.

The error messages you get seem to indicate the same, but in your case (and mine) it's not `MEMORYCLERK_SQLLOGPOOL` that's taking a lot of memory but `MEMORYCLERK_XE` that's taking up more memory than you would expect.

After investigation which XE sessions where running it came up with the system_health and 2 Sharepoint sessions (and you seem to be hosting sharepoint too).
Those 2 sessions log to the ring buffer target (and log quite a lot of events).

The good news is that according to some blog posts it's still fixed in SP2 for SQL Server 2012 and after a week on SP3 the XE memory clerk seems to be under control.

Related reading:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/ea3b1e29-d288-4f41-a3f8-3fa1b71e3e82/memoryclerkxe-consuming-30-gb-memory-of-100-gb
- https://geertvanhove.wordpress.com/2015/07/02/memoryclerk_xe-and-sharepoint/

From Geert:

> This behaviour is generated by extended events most likely created by
>   Sharepoint monitoring and logging information into memory ring
>   buffers. Disabling ring buffers or a correct configuration of ring
>   buffers should solve this issue.
>
> Wrong, this is a known issue with Sharepoint on SQL Server 2012 SP1.
>   After installing SP2 en restarting the instance, the problem was
>   solved. However, I suggested to keep on monitoring memory clerks for
>   another few weeks.

PS: these errors where also observed in my environment: [Using ‘dbghelp.dll’ version ‘4.0.5’](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/using-dbghelp-dll-version-4-0-5-error-fixed-in-sql-server-2012-sp1-cu6/)

Edit: I can confirm I haven't seen any issues with this server for months so it looks as if the update addressed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server in your case is patched to `SP1`. Microsoft has released [SQL Server 2012 SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=43340) and there was fix for such type of errors.

As per [Microsoft Article](https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2769594) reason is

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 may experience some out-of-memory errors
>   because of an internal memory leak. In this situation, the leaked
>   memory is consumed by the MEMORYCLERK_SQLLOGPOOL memory clerk that is
>   used internally for transaction log activities. For example, the
>   MEMORYCLERK_SQLLOGPOOL memory clerk is used internally for the
>   following transaction log activities:
>
> AlwaysOn change-capturing activities on the primary replicas
>
> AlwaysOn redo manager activities on the secondary availability
>   replicas

The article says that issue was fixed in `CU2/CU5 for SQL Server 2012 SP1`. But since Microsoft released SQL Server 2012 SP2 this would contain all such fixes and `I highly urge you to apply SP2 ASAP`.